# Vertex array buffers for a windowing system

Tags: c#, opengl, vertex-buffer

I want to add a very basic "windowing system" in my game, mainly to display stuff like: minimap, stats, dialogs, etc. I'm currently working in C# using OpenTK and I'm using VBOs and VAOs to store all my models.

If I were to use a VAO for my windows, would that be overkill? Would I do the same with my controls in the window? I need full flexibility (be able to change the controls whenever I want), so having a single VAO for all the controls and window is probably not the best alternative. Currently, I'm only rendering the window frame and content background using a VAO storing vertices, colors and indices in their individual VBOs.

Is there a better, more efficient way of storing my window's data and controls?

Comment: I've done one toolkit with Opentk in c#, (https://github.com/jpbruyere/GOLib) For now, I use only one quad to render interface...

Comment: If you are using core OpenGL, then you _have_ to use VAOs. Though for square/rectangle things, you can use the same VAO and change the transform matrices, textures, and shaders for each element.